# How to reference variable dynamically in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
PROJECT_ID = 'test'
BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = 'categories'
BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS = 'manufacturers'
list = [BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES, BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS]
table_categories = PROJECT_ID + '.'  + BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES
table_manufacturers = PROJECT_ID + '.' + BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS

for table in list:
    ....
    source_objects=['table_{0}'.format(table)]  #reference to the correct var
    ....
```

This however puts string inside `source_objects`. I want it to reference the variables (whatever is saved in the variables)
meaning what I actually want is **equivalent** of this:

When `table = BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES`

```
source_objects = [ table_categories ]
```

When `table = BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS`

```
source_objects = [ table_manufacturers ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the contents on `table_categories` inside a list? Or do you just want to reference it's string value?

Comment: Also, it is bad practice to override the built-in `list` object.

Comment: @RottenCandy I want the refrence... source_objects should contain whatever table_categories  contains.. Just like I would do : source_objects = [ table_categories ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the eval() function to turn strings into variable:
[read on eval](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval)

```
PROJECT_ID = 'test'
BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES = 'categories'
BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS = 'manufacturers'
mylist = [BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES, BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS]
table_categories = PROJECT_ID + '.'  + BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES
table_manufacturers = PROJECT_ID + '.' + BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS

for table in mylist:
    source_objects=eval('table_{0}'.format(table)) #reference to the correct var
    print source_objects
```

output:

> ```
> test.categories
> test.manufacturers
> ```

also as noted in comments, you really shouldn't override list, and use mylist or whatever instead

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are trying to do is store the values of `table_categories` and `table_manufacturers` inside a list called `source_objects`.
Assuming the `table_...` variables are global,

```
suffixes = [BQ_TABLE_NAME_CATEGORIES, BQ_TABLE_NAME_MANUFACTURERS]

source_objects = []
for s in suffixes:
    source_objects.append(globals['table_{0}'.append(s)])
    ...
```

This would get you:

```
>>> source_objects
['test.categories', 'test.manufacturers']
```

And if the `table_...` variables are not global, use `locals()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals